# Two records limit when the same column

Tags: mysql, orm, kohana

I have column:

id | id_contract | price

I'd like to select all with the limit 2 the cheapest offer from one contract.

I use kochana ORM.

Thanks.

For example

```
1 | 1 | 100 *
2 | 1 | 500
3 | 1 | 300 *
4 | 1 | 900
5 | 2 | 1000
6 | 2 | 100 *
7 | 2 | 200 *
8 | 3 | 10000 *
```

- - This is what I want to select.

Comment: If you want an answer, edit your question and add sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in MySQL with the following query:

```
select t.*
from table t
where (select count(*)
       from table t2
       where t2.id_contract = t.id_contract and
             t2.price <= t.price
      ) <= 2;
```